# Web page pre-populate fields with own values

Tags: browser, passwords

We have a website which is hosted at IIS (localhost/r). It has a username and password field. Just wondering if there is any add-on for firefox or google chrome where I can save those fields and so that every time I don't have to re-enter them. I tried we developer add on for firefox but it pre-populates the password field with memorized text "password".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the inbuilt *Password Manager* for Firefox?

It should prompt you if you wish to save the password for the current site.

If you don't have this enabled go to Tools -> Options -> Security
And then select "Remember passwords for sites".

Let me know if i have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't work because it's our internal site and it never asks for saving password. That's because for us it's a password (human user) but the website doesn't knows that. For the website it's like someone entering some text in a text field. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the website? Can you change the text field into a password field?

Failing that you could always install the Greasemonkey addon, which would allow you to write a script to enter the password in every time for you.